# Base framework used in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal

I want to start development in Drupal and i was curious to know that which framework is used as a base of Drupal is Symfony or custom or its a fusion of their custom and the pic some of things from other frame works like synfony because i was reading this artical https://cipix.nl/understanding-drupal-8-part-1-general-structure-framework and here this author mentions symfony as well.

Comment: it's drupal....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base framework used in Drupal 8 is Symfony 2.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/getting-started-background-prerequisites-drupal-8

Comment: Drupal uses part of Symfony, but it's not the base framework for Drupal.